# What is com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.ActionDescriptor?

Tags: java, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have found it in one of private Atlassian's plugins to Jira projects.

```
import com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.ActionDescriptor;
```

and there is nothing like this in `pom.xml`.
I can't find a maven dependency for it.

IDE shouts it is an error, but `atlassian-run` can compile it.

Comment: yes and where it comes from in the project I got when there is no any depdendency like this?

Answer (score 0):

> com.opensymphony.workflow

is a sub dependency of

> com.atlassian.jira.jira-core

What IDE are you using?